# Spark java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String; local class incompatible

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

I'm attempting to run my Spark applicaiton on a remote cluster and I'm getting serialization errors. The Scala and Spark version are the same. I'm stuck at this point.

spark-shell -version on the cluster:

```
root@a913008dd071:/usr/local/spark-2.1.1# ./bin/spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_131
Branch
Compiled by user jenkins on 2017-04-25T23:51:10Z
Revision
Url
Type --help for more information.
```

build.sbt

```
import sbt.ExclusionRule

name := "hxfa"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val elasticVersion = "5.4.1"

resolvers += "Spark Packages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"
resolvers += "Additional spark packages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/sbcd90/org.apache.spark"
resolvers += "Apache HBase" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases"
resolvers += "Thrift" at "http://people.apache.org/~rawson/repo/"
resolvers += "Spring Plugins" at "http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/"

/* Dependencies */
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // Framework and configuration
  "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-web" % "1.5.4.RELEASE",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-validator" % "5.2.4.Final",

  /* Serializations */
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.7",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.7",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.7",
  "com.esotericsoftware" % "kryo" % "4.0.0",


  // Spark and utilities
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0" ,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.0" ,
  "graphframes" % "graphframes" % "0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11",


  // Spark connectors
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11" % elasticVersion,
  "org.mongodb.spark" % "mongo-spark-connector_2.11" % "2.0.0",


  //JDBC
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.35",

  // HBase
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "1.2.4",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.2.4",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.2.4",

  // OrientDB
  "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-graphdb" % "2.2.20"

).map(_.excludeAll(ExclusionRule("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"), ExclusionRule("log4j", "log4j")))

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.2.4"
).map(_.excludeAll(
  ExclusionRule("com.sun.jersey", "jersey-server"),
  ExclusionRule("tomcat"),
  ExclusionRule("log4j", "log4j")
))


/* Assembly     */

mainClass in assembly := Some("com.x.x.hello.app.HX")
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false, includeDependency = false)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Stack trace:

> java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -2992553500466442037, local class serialVersionUID = -5670082246090726217
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1843) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:1.0.0-M1]
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:1.0.0-M1]
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:1.0.0-M1]
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

spark-submit --version displays the spark and scala version of its package and not of your system whereas your sbt is taking the scala version of your system. So

Please change

```
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0" ,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.0" ,
```

to

```
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.1" ,
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.1.1" ,
```

And if it doesn't help, please update your question with your system scala version, how you are submitting the application and your remote machine's scala and spark version.

Comment: I didn't missed the version difference. Thanks!

Comment: did you try above suggestion?

Comment: I'm attempting it right now. I will close the question if it will work.

Comment: if it works, don't close it. upvote and accept my answer. :)

Comment: I said "close" but meant "accept the answer". I already upvoted. :)

Comment: Thats great . Thanks :)